# Update database info with onclick button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, button, onclick

I need some help with a button `onClick`.

```
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="this.disabled=true; ^FUNCTION TO UPDATE^"> 
<button type="button" id="2" onclick="this.disabled=true; ^FUNCTION TO UPDATE^"> 
<button type="button" id="3" onclick="this.disabled=true; ^FUNCTION TO UPDATE^">
```

With this code I disable the button that was pressed, but I also need to update info in a database sending the id, something like this:

```
UPDATE reservation SET status='approved' WHERE id=^ID OF THE CLICKED BUTTON^
```

I need it to be loaded in the same page without sending it with `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery, more specifically it's [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) functionality. It's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: "I need it to be loaded in the same page without sending it with POST or GET." - Why this requirement? Whether it's through an explicit POST (GET should not be used for this purpose...) or through Ajax it's the same and only way you can update information in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax call for this eg:

```
$.get('update_reservation.php', {id: 1});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for more info.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with jQuery as I'd like to be. Can this call be put directly in the onClick attribute?

Answer (score 0):

With plain javascript you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var page = "dbupdate.php"; // hardcode this elsewhere out of sight

function update(target,data){
document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = 'sending...';
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       req = new XMLHttpRequest();
       req.onreadystatechange = function() {ajaxDone(target);};
       req.open("POST", page, true);
       req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       req.send("data=" + data );
   // IE/Windows ActiveX version
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
       req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (req) {
           req.onreadystatechange = function() {ajaxDone(target);};
           req.open("POST", page, true);
           req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           req.send("data=" + data );

       }
   }
}  

function ajaxDone(target) {
    // only if req is "loaded"
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // only if "OK"
        if (req.status == 200 || req.status == 304) {
           results = req.responseText;
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = results;
        } else {
           document.getElementById(target).innerHTML="ajax error:\n" +
            req.statusText;
        }
    }
}
// -->
</script>
```

For output make sure you have a div with the id equal to target.