# function and php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update database info with onclick button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559868/update-database-info-with-onclick-button)

I have a onclick button which calls a function with php inside of it to query a database. The code works fine separately, but together, it does nothing. After looking through some answers it says I have to place the query database code into a separate PHP file, and somehow call that file on the users onclick ? Is that the best option, and if so, can anyone provide an example of how I would call the PHP database lookup file from an onclick button ? Thanks in advance.

```
<div onClick="newUser();"
style="position:absolute;display: block; cursor:pointer; top: 100px; left: 600px;">
<img src="assets/invite.png">
</div>



<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php       
function newUser(){
// Make a MySQL Connection
$me = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']));
$uid = $me->id;
echo "$uid";

$hostname="";
$username="";
$password="";
$dbname="mpsuserdata";
$usertable="userdata";
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die ("Could not connect");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO userdata 
(id, name, startdate, enddate, shop) VALUES('11111111' , 'UK', '$startdate' , '$enddate' , 'test' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Data Inserted!";
            }
?>
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? It sounds like you are trying to include PHP code directly inside of JavaScript, and you're not getting the results you want. If that's the case, you need to use Ajax to return the data that you need.

Comment: Andrew. Being a new user, it will not let me submit code as yet. I think your Ajax reference is correct, i am only updating a database, so I just need to know how to call the PHP from within the javascript? Thanks for your time.

Comment: edit your question and paste portion of your code that related to your question **IN** question box.

Answer (score 3):

Use **AJAX**..

AJAX is the very much easy solution for you. you can put JavaScript function on your button on-click event.
and call jquery.ajax function for that. you can now use your php page for execute query for your database.

```
function ajaxfunc()
{
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "query_page.php",
            data:   "queryfields",
            success: function(html){
            // data you want to return on.
            }
        });

}
```

i think this makes you happy and satisfied.

Comment: +1 Superb description with nice example.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done through ajax post/get method for more please go through the [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)